# Deserialize json data without using Json.net

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, scheduled-tasks

I am working in schedule agent. I have data in json format in schedule agent. I tried *Json.net* in schedule agent to deserialize json into list, but it is not working in schedule agent.

Can anyone tell me how I can deserialize json data into a list format without using Jsonssoft.dll??

I am using following code to convert json to list but it is giving me null in childlist...

```
    List<ConferenceModel> childlist = new List<ConferenceModel>();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseContent));
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(childlist.GetType());
    childlist = ser.ReadObject(ms) as List<ConferenceModel>;
```

Here is ConferenceModel class

```
public class Conference 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string updateDateTime { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    private bool _isEditDeleteVisible;

}
public class ConferenceModel
{
    public List<Conference> conferences { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does WP8 have [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes, In WP8 DataContractJsonSerializer is there. How I can use it?

Comment: Um... add a reference if needed; add a `using` directive if needed; then just `new` a `DataContractJsonSerializer` and use it as per the examples in MSDN?

Comment: Could you show us the code for ConferenceModel? Keep in mind that it has to be marked with the DataContract attribute, and its members with the DataMember attribute.

Comment: Sorry Its JsonSoft pakage, which uses to serialize and deserialize json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the DataContract annotation in your model + use the **DataContractJsonSerializer** and it should work just fine:

```
[DataContract]
public class Conference
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string updateDateTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int duration { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    private bool _isEditDeleteVisible;
}

[DataContract]
public class ConferenceModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Conference> conferences { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:
The code needs to be fixed as well - this worked for me:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ConferenceModel));
ConferenceModel childlist = (ConferenceModel)ser.ReadObject(ms);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it but still I am getting null value in "childlist". following is json that i have to convert in list                          {"conferences":[{"id":"1369","datetime":"2014-02-19 11:52:00","duration":15,"description":""},{"id":"1371","datetime":"2014-02-19 16:53:00","duration":15,"description":""}]}

Comment: I see the problem now, I've the fix to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I figured I'd share.  I was also looking for a reliable JSON library that supported dynamic objects.  JSON.NET is too large if you just need a simple JSON parser, in my opinion.

So I wrote the below class.  It's also on GitHub and NuGet.

GitHub: https://github.com/Jay-Rad/JSON_Helper

NuGet: Install-Package JSON_Helper

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace JSON_Helper
{
    public static class JSON
    {
        private static JavaScriptSerializer Serializer { get; } = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        public static string Encode(object JsonObject)
        {
            return Serializer.Serialize(JsonObject);
        }
        public static T Decode<T>(string JsonString)
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(JsonString);
        }
        public static dynamic Decode(string JsonString)
        {
            var deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(JsonString);
            dynamic result = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in deserialized)
            {
                ((IDictionary<string, object>)result).Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```